# Nonanalytic functions with Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

According to Wikipedia:

> Formally, a function $f$ is *real analytic* on an open set $D$ in the real line if for any $x_0\in D$ one can write
>
> $$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n}=a_{0}+a_{1}(x-x_{0})+a_{2}(x-x_{0})^{2}+a_{3}(x-x_{0})^{3}+\cdots$$
>
> in which the coefficients $a_{0},a_{1},\dots$ are real numbers and the series is convergent to $f(x)$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

This seems stronger than the requirement that $f(x)$ simply has a Taylor series about some point $a$, convergent everywhere in some neighborhood of $a$.

Does this mean that there is, e.g. a real function, $q(x)$, with a valid Taylor series expansion about $a$ but no valid convergent Taylor series of $q(x)$ about any other point arbitrarily close to $a$ (i.e. a real function with a Taylor series about $a$ that fails to be real analytic on any open set containing $a$) or does the fact that a function has a Taylor series about $a$ that converges over some neighborhood of $a$ to the function necessarily imply that it is real analytic on some neighborhood of $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a infinitely differentiable function $f$ whose Taylor series is convergent, but does not converge to $f$. Consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. If you calculate its derivatives at $0$, you'll see that they're all $0$. So the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ converges to the constant $0$ function.

You may wonder, after this, what Taylor's theorem [actually says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). It only says that the finite sums of the Taylor series are asymptotic to the function, not that they sum to it.

---

After clarification, it seems you are looking for a function $f$ such that:

i) $f$ has a Taylor series $(a_n (z-x)^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ at a point $x$.

ii) There exists some interval $(v,w)$ containing $x$ on which $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (z- x)^n$ (this is implied by the statement with open neighbourhoods)

iii) But $f$ is not real analytic for points arbitrarily close to $x$.

In fact, (iii) cannot hold for any function for which (ii) holds, for the following reason. You can find in standard textbooks on complex analysis the fact that if a power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_i (z-x)$ converges for some point $y \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $y \neq x$, then the power series converges to a complex analytic function on an open disc containing $x$ and $y$ (for example, Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, Theorem 10.6 and its Corollary). A complex analytic function is real analytic on any subset of the reals on which it is defined (though it may still be complex-valued), so the power series defines a real analytic function on the interval $(v,w)$. As $f$ agrees with the power series there, and $f$ is real-valued, this shows that $f$ is a real-analytic function on the open interval $(v,w)$. Therefore the Taylor series of any $y \in (v,w)$ converges to $f$ in some open interval.

Comment: Sorry I have been a bit sloppy with the question. I'll fix it. Apologies. Hope that clarifies - I am assuming the function has a convergent Taylor series expansion.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 The example I gave *does* have a convergent Taylor expansion.

Comment: I may be a bit unsure about the terminology here, but (as far as I know) generally a a function's series expansion is a series which converges to the function (over the relevant domain). Regardless, apologies for the possible lack of clarity.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 The Taylor series of some function $f$ at a point $x$ is a power series. It may converge to a function, or not (if not, the $f$ is not analytic). Even if it converges to a function $g$, it is only necessarily the case that $g(x) = f(x)$, and not necessarily $g(y) = f(y)$ for any other $y$, no matter how close to $x$. The function $f$ is analytic on a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ if the Taylor series at $x$ converges *and* it converges to $f$ on $U$, not to some other function.

Comment: I am aware of this. I have clarified in the question and in my comments that requirement of my question is for a function, $q$ with a Taylor series about $a$ that converges to $q$ itself in some neighborhood of $a$ but has no valid Taylor series expansion about any other point arbitrarily near $a$, i.e. there is no open set $D$ that one can plug in to the Wikipedia definition of real analytic (in my question) that would satisfy the requirements for real analycity.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 Every power series defines an analytic function on its domain of convergence, so if $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ on $D$, then $f$ is analytic for each point of $D$. It follows that there is no such function.

Comment: I see. It would be helpful if you could elaborate on this in your answer with relevant references for proofs, etc. Thank you for your comments.